# A question about $KP + V = L$ and $KP$ set theory.

Tags: set-theory, proof-theory

In reading Rathjen (Choice principles in constructive set theories) and Jager (On Feferman's OST) I've come across two facts that are taken as obvious/well known, and probably are, but for which I cannot find a reference/work out how to prove. Either a reference or even just a hint in the right direction of how they might be shown would be much appreciated!!

The two facts are very similar:

1) $KP + V = L$ is conservative over $KP$ for $\Sigma_1$ formulae (Rathjen,p10)

2) $KP + V = L$ is conservative over $KP$ for absolute formulae (Jager, p30)

*in both cases the axiom of infinity is assumed.

As I say even just a general proof strategy for working out such claims would be much (perhaps more) appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The axioms of KP are enough to define and construct $L$ as usual: if $M$ is a model of KP, then $M$ has a definable transitive subclass $L^M$ containing all the ordinals of $M$ which is a model of KP+V=L. (This is proved in detail in [Barwise's book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235418470).) $\Sigma_1$ sentences are upwards absolute, so every $\Sigma_1$ sentence true in $L^M$ is true already in $M$.

This means that if $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_1$ consequence of KP+V=L, then $\varphi$ must already be a consequence of KP: otherwise taking a model $M$ of KP+$\neg\varphi$ and considering $L^M$ gives a contradiction.

This proves (1); (2) is identical, since the required absoluteness property is there folded in directly as a hypothesis ("absolute formula").